# Set Guzzle 5 Config After Instantiation

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Currently, we send in Guzzle v5 configuration parameter to the constructor of the GuzzleClient. As an **example** only, something like:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['verify' => false ]);
```

Is there a way to instantiate the Guzzle object without sending in the constructor parameter?  And then later set the config, but before the actual call/action to .post or .get, etc.?  Something like:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient();
$this->client->config = ['verify' => false ];
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't easier to instantiate only before the actual call, and then set the options the way you want? Like `$config = [... some config...];` then `$this->client = new GuzzleClient($config);`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Thanks, but I'm looking to not send configuration into the constructor at all.